# if location is not approved - swift

Tags: swift, location

So, I have location working currently and all tests seem fine - that is as long as I get the users location.

I am wondering if the user chooses not to share their location with the app, I want it to still fire a function.

I am wondering how to do this?

My first thought was adding it to the following function

```
func isLocationServicesEnabled() -> Bool {
      if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
          switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {
          case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
              return false
          case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
              return true
          @unknown default:
              return false
          }
      }

      return false
  }
```

but I thought maybe that is not the smartest place to put it as that function is used by

```
if isLocationServicesEnabled() {
           locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
           locationManager.delegate = self
           locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } else {
           locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
```

So my thinking is to place it in this if query.

I am wondering if this is a smart place to put it or if someone has any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you understand your question correctly, you always want to get the user’s location even if he refuses to use his location?
If this is true:
Firstly:
This is totally unethical
Secondly:
This is against Apple's rules
Thirdly:
Your application will likely be rejected when trying to upload it to AppStore.

Comment: No we are not trying to get users location (GEO location) what we would do is check the IP address of the user - spotify does this so as per your unethical it's not. its required to protect content that should only be accessed by users in 1 country or another.